# What does $\lim \inf _ { n \rightarrow \infty }$ mean?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

I'm new into Mathematical Analysis, and my textbook says:

> Consider the series: $\frac { 1 } { 2 } + \frac { 1 } { 3 } + \frac {
>  1 } { 2 ^ { 2 } } + \frac { 1 } { 3 ^ { 2 } } + \frac { 1 } { 2 ^ { 3
>  } } + \frac { 1 } { 3 ^ { 3 } } + \frac { 1 } { 2 ^ { 4 } } + \frac {
>  1 } { 3 ^ { 4 } } + \cdots$
>
> for which
>
> $\liminf _ { n \rightarrow \infty } \frac { a _ { n + 1 } } { a _ { n
>  } } = \lim _ { n \rightarrow \infty } \left( \frac { 2 } { 3 } \right)
>  ^ { n } = 0$
>
> $\liminf _ { n \rightarrow \infty } \sqrt [ n ] { a _ { n } } = \lim _
>  { n \rightarrow \infty } \sqrt [ 2 n ] { \frac { 1 } { 3 ^ { n } } } =
>  \frac { 1 } { \sqrt { 3 } }$
>
> $\limsup _ { n \rightarrow \infty } \sqrt [ n ] { a _ { n } } = \lim _
>  { n \rightarrow \infty } \sqrt [ 2 n ] { \frac { 1 } { 2 ^ { n } } } =
>  \frac { 1 } { \sqrt { 2 } }$
>
> $\limsup _ { n \rightarrow \infty } \frac { a _ { n + 1 } } { a _ { n
>  } } = \lim _ { n \rightarrow \infty } \frac { 1 } { 2 } \left( \frac {
>  3 } { 2 } \right) ^ { n } = + \infty$

My question is: What does $\lim \inf _ { n \rightarrow \infty }$ mean? 
And why $\lim \inf _ { n \rightarrow \infty } \frac { a _ { n + 1 } } { a _ { n > } } = \lim _ { n \rightarrow \infty } \left( \frac { 2 } { 3 } \right)$?

Comment: Maybe try [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_superior_and_limit_inferior)

Comment: Which textbook are you reading? Can you give us the reference? It is impossible that the book uses an operator such as "lim inf" without defining it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can refer to your notes or to the wiki page [Limit superior and limit inferior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_superior_and_limit_inferior) for the definition.

It is just a generalization for the limit of a sequence, in particular we consider

$$I_n=\inf\{a_n:k\ge n\}$$

and since $I_n$ is an increasing sequence the limit always exist (finite or infinite) and then we can consider and define

$$\liminf_{n\to \infty} a_n =\lim_{n\to \infty} I_n $$

To show that for a given sequence $a_n$ we have $\liminf_{n\to \infty} a_n =L$ we need to show two fact

- $a_n \ge b_n \quad b_n\to L$
- find a sub-sequence $a_{i_n}$ such that $a_{i_n}\to L$

Comment: Thank you! Do you also know why in this case $\inf \sqrt [ n ] { a _ { n } }$ = $\sqrt [ 2 n ] { \frac { 1 } { 3 ^ { n } } }$? I might deduce that since it takes the inferior, it is $1/3^n$, but I cannot explain the "2n root".

Comment: @KevinMoore Note simply that $\sqrt[n] a_n=\sqrt[n] {\frac1{2^n}}=\frac12$ for $n$ odd and for $n$ even $\sqrt[n] a_n=\sqrt[n] {\frac1{3^{n/2}}}=\frac1{\sqrt 3}$.

Comment: Your last paragraph "To show that..." mentions two points and the first point is not right. Consider the sequence $a_n=(-1)^n\left(1+\dfrac{1}{n}\right)$. Then $\liminf_{n\to\infty} a_n=-1$ and yet for all odd values of $n$ we have $a_n<-1$.

Comment: In general there is no systematic way to find the liminf or limsup because they don't follow laws like "algebra of limits".

Comment: @ParamanandSingh What I mean is that we have $\forall n \quad a_n \ge -\left(1+\frac1n\right) \implies \liminf a_n \ge -1$ and $a_{2n+1} \to -1$. From here we can conclude that $\liminf a_n =-1$. That's the standard way I've learned in my courses.

Comment: But your point $a_n\geq L$ (at the end of answer) is not the same as what you mention in your last comment. You should edit that.

Comment: Perhaps you should write like "bound the sequence $a_n$ from below like $a_n\geq b_n$ where $b_n\to L$ and show that there is a subsequence of $a_n$ which also converges to $L$.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh Yes exactly, I need to clarify better that point. Thanks, as usual your observation are always a great benefit for this site, for me and for the asker. Bye

Comment: Your sequence $I_n$ is actually increasing, not decreasing. Indeed, $I_n$ is the lower of $a_n$ and $I_{n+1}$, so in any case $I_{n+1} \ge I_n$.

Comment: @NajibIdrissi That's absolutely right of course for liminf case. Thanks I fix that!